# How to find the strongest frequency in a signal using a microcontroller/circuit?

Tags: rf, signal, frequency, circuits, transmission

I am trying to implement a low-power backscatter transmitter+receiver and ran into some trouble on the transmission side.

Setup: My transmitter circuit sends a 50MHz wave, which the receiver circuit uses to toggle itself on and off at ~19-21kHz. When the transmitter samples its transmission signal, it sees a long time series of 50MHz (5Vpp) with a very weak 20kHz (~2mVpp) modulation riding on top of it. The rate of the modulation is the "data" that the receiver is sending back to the transmitter.

Now, when I look at the transmitter signal in the frequency domain with Python, the 20kHz modulation is clear as day, and the peak finding is easy. Y-axis is unscaled, please ignore.

[image]

But I don't want to use Python. I would like to find the strongest frequency peak near 20kHz with only a microcontroller.

- Currently I'm not using the microcontroller because I think it would take too much memory and processing power to do the FFT continuously.
- And I'm not using a frequency/voltage converter because I think the modulated signal (few mVpp) is too weak for those circuits to detect.
- A few op amps with tight filters could boost the modulated signal to a detectable level, but I'm worried it would still be too noisy for F/V.
- I considered a single frequency FFT, but I need to be able to detect when the peak frequency changes, and what it changes to.

I am hoping there is a better way to find the peak frequency, perhaps using supporting circuitry?

I'm also open to alternative methods for the receiver to modulate its data onto the carrier wave. Currently, the receiver reads a sensor's voltage to set the modulation frequency, so the frequency always shifts. I'd like to do FSK (static frequency turned on and off as bits) but don't know of a simple way to generate FSK on the receive side.

EDIT: The receiver's modulation outputs a continuous frequency, so imagine the low and high end of an analog sensor outputting 19kHz and 21kHz respectively, with all the intermediate values mapping in between. At least under the current scheme, it's important for me to find the precise modulation frequency from the transmitter.

Comment: It's fairly straightforward to measure frequency if the signal to noise ratio is adequate, do you have a guarranteed SNR?

Comment: This all depends on what kind of hardware you got and how it might translate the radio signal before handing it to the microcontroller. The problem isn't finding the peak when you got everything translated to digital data, the problem is getting it translated in the first place.

Comment: Exactly how did you get the data for this Python analysis?

Comment: Andy, this sounds like *ambient backscatter*. Is that what you are doing? (Just to be sure.)

Comment: It's possible to detect a single frequency (or two in your case) by multiplying the signal with sin() and cos() of the frequency and average that, but the local "oscillator" that makes the sin and cos has to be synchronized with the transmitter.

Comment: Lock in detection seems like a good choice here.

Comment: @BruceAbbott This data is streamed from the TX over serial to my computer, then I did the graphing offline

Comment: @periblepsis I think it's just regular backscatter since I'm using a transmitter that sends a pre-decided carrier wave, instead of the RX harvesting/sinking off whatever's around.

Comment: @Neil_UK my SNR will vary but I think can be guaranteed at a low value. What did you have in mind for measuring frequency?

Comment: @user1850479 from my understanding, lock-in is good for finding how much of one frequency there is in the signal. Since I'm more interested in finding what frequency it is, are you recommending something like scanning the lock-in frequency across a set range to find the strongest freq?

Comment: @Lundin That's what I'm sayin' ! I don't know of any ways to translate it

Comment: Can you feed a PLL with the signal?

Comment: @AndyK There's a lot of research that's been taking place since I first read about and spoke with folks at the University of Washington, circa 2013. Part of that is to use defined transmitter sources so that the environment is known and controlled within a building. So I still consider that part and parcel. If that's what you are doing, anyway.

Comment: It sounded like the modulation comes from your receiver, in which case the receiver itself could lock in to get the amplitude/phase of the signal using itself as the clock source. If that's not what you're doing then it would be more complex and you'd have to tune a filter around (which is similar to an optimized FFT that only computes the likely frequency bins).

Comment: _"This data is streamed from the TX over serial to my computer"_  - what does this data represent? you talk about op amps with filters etc. so I presume you want to process the analog output of the transmitter, right? How do you intend to get that?